# How to apply the same command to a list of files in Bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, substitution, backticks

I mean some command subtitutions. In the past I was able to use backticks in Bash, when for example I had to download a list of files / links which had been already collected in a text file, line by line:

```
wget `cat list.txt`
```

and even megadl to download from mega:

```
megadl `cat list.txt`
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work right now as expected for some reason. I get the whole file list as a long line of text separated by spaces instead of newlines.

I often write small scripts which can handle only one argument which is a file, but not a list of files, listed in a text file. Of course I don't want to modify my scripts, because Bash provide this helper mechanism, to apply the same command to a list of files, for example on the output of "ls -1 *.jpg". I have a small utility called "cgamma" which apply gamma correction to image files while preserving the colour saturation ( it simply calls imagemagick's mogrify). And I would like to use it on many image files, like this:

```
cgamma `ls -1 *.jpg` 1.3
```

I know I could use a for loop one-liner, but it is more typing:

```
for $i in $(ls -1 *.jpg);do cgamma $i 1.3;done
```

So my question is, how can I use properly the backticks, command substitution, to process file lists, and apply the same command to all of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xargs`:

```
printf '%s\0' *.jpg | xargs -0 -I {} cgamma '{}' 1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually shorten your putative `for` loop by using `bash` to do the globbing for you - rather than parsing the output of `ls` which is best avoided:

```
for i in *.jpg; do cgamma "$i" 1.3; done
```

That is actually shorter than your accepted solution :-)

Further, you could use `GNU Parallel` and not only make the command shorter, but also have them all gamma-corrected *in parallel* and make use of all those lovely Intel cores you paid top dollar for ;-)

```
parallel cgamma {} 1.3 ::: *.jpg
```

Comment: Thx, I accepted the xargs answer because it was new to me, I didn't know what this utility is good for.